# Need to rearrange data using sort command

Tags: awk, uniq

I have below data named atp.csv file

```
Date_Time,M_ID,N_ID,Status,Desc,AMount,Type
2015-01-05 00:00:00 076,1941321748,BD9010423590206,200,Transaction Successful,2000,PRETOP
2015-01-05 00:00:00 077,1941323504,BD9010423590207,351,Transaction Successful,5000,PRETOP
2015-01-05 00:00:00 078,1941321743,BD9010423590205,200,Transaction Successful,1500,PRETOP
2015-01-05 00:00:00 391,1941323498,BD9010500000003,200,Transaction Successful,1000,PRETOP
```

i want to count status wise using below command.

```
cat atp.csv|awk -F',' '{print $4}'|sort|uniq -c
```

The output is like below:

```
3 200
1 351
```

But i want to like below output...

```
200,3
351,1
```

That is status is first and then count value.

Comment: Side note: that's a "useless use of cat": you can simply give the filename to `awk`.

Comment: ok. please provide the command to get the actual output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk again to swap the columns:

```
awk -F, '{print $4}' atp.csv | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2","$1}'
```

Comment: Yep. This appeared while I was closing my bracket...

Comment: @John: thanks for your answer. Can you please help me once more. i want to sum the Amount column in Status_wise..like below.
200,3,4500
351,1,5000

Comment: Please ask a separate question.  But try writing the code yourself first.  :)  You can use awk to do it.